# GPUImage custom OpenGL ES shader resulting in black image

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, gpuimage

Working on another OpenGL ES image filter based on [this](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/glfx.js/blob/master/src/filters/adjust/streetphoto.js):

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float amount;
uniform vec2 texSize;
varying vec2 texCoord;
void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, texCoord);
    vec4 orig = color;

    /* High pass filter */
    vec4 highpass = color * 5.0;

    float dx = 1.0 / texSize.x;
    float dy = 1.0 / texSize.y;
    highpass += texture2D(texture, texCoord + vec2(-dx, -dy)) * -0.625;
    highpass += texture2D(texture, texCoord + vec2(dx, -dy)) * -0.625;
    highpass += texture2D(texture, texCoord + vec2(dx, dy)) * -0.625;
    highpass += texture2D(texture, texCoord + vec2(-dx, dy)) * -0.625;
    highpass += texture2D(texture, texCoord + vec2(-dx * 2.0, -dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
    highpass += texture2D(texture, texCoord + vec2(dx * 2.0, -dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
    highpass += texture2D(texture, texCoord + vec2(dx * 2.0, dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
    highpass += texture2D(texture, texCoord + vec2(-dx * 2.0, dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
    highpass.a = 1.0;

    /* Overlay blend */
    vec3 overlay = vec3(1.0);
    if (highpass.r <= 0.5) {
        overlay.r = 2.0 * color.r * highpass.r;
    } else {
        overlay.r = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - color.r) * (1.0 - highpass.r);
    }
    if (highpass.g <= 0.5) {
        overlay.g = 2.0 * color.g * highpass.g;
    } else {
        overlay.g = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - color.g) * (1.0 - highpass.g);
    }
    if (highpass.b <= 0.5) {
        overlay.b = 2.0 * color.b * highpass.b;
    } else {
        overlay.b = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - color.b) * (1.0 - highpass.b);
    }
    color.rgb = (overlay * 0.8) + (orig.rgb * 0.2);

    /* Desaturated hard light */
    vec3 desaturated = vec3(orig.r + orig.g + orig.b / 3.0);
    if (desaturated.r <= 0.5) {
        color.rgb = 2.0 * color.rgb * desaturated;
    } else {
        color.rgb = vec3(1.0) - vec3(2.0) * (vec3(1.0) - color.rgb) * (vec3(1.0) - desaturated);
    }
    color = (orig * 0.6) + (color * 0.4);

    /* Add back some color */
    float average = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;
    color.rgb += (average - color.rgb) * (1.0 - 1.0 / (1.001 - 0.45));

    gl_FragColor = (color * amount) + (orig * (1.0 - amount));
}
```

Per my [question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997762/gpuimage-shader-crashing-with-error-one-or-more-attached-shaders-not-successfu), I knew to assign precision to each float and vec. This time it compiled fine, however when I go to apply the filter in GPUImage (e.g. by setting the value of `clarity` to `0.8`), the image goes black. My gut tells me this is related to the texture size, but without knowing how GPUImage handles that, I'm kinda stuck.

Here's my implementation in Objective-C:

**.h**

```
#import <GPUImage/GPUImage.h>

@interface GPUImageClarityFilter : GPUImageFilter
{
    GLint clarityUniform;
}

// Gives the image a gritty, surreal contrasty effect
// Value 0 to 1
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) GLfloat clarity;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "GPUImageClarityFilter.h"

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE
NSString *const kGPUImageClarityFragmentShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform lowp float clarity;
 uniform highp vec2 textureSize;
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
 void main() {
     highp vec4 color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
     highp vec4 orig = color;

     /* High pass filter */
     highp vec4 highpass = color * 5.0;

     highp float dx = 1.0 / textureSize.x;
     highp float dy = 1.0 / textureSize.y;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(-dx, -dy)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(dx, -dy)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(dx, dy)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(-dx, dy)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(-dx * 2.0, -dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(dx * 2.0, -dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(dx * 2.0, dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(-dx * 2.0, dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
     highpass.a = 1.0;

     /* Overlay blend */
     highp vec3 overlay = vec3(1.0);
     if (highpass.r <= 0.5) {
         overlay.r = 2.0 * color.r * highpass.r;
     } else {
         overlay.r = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - color.r) * (1.0 - highpass.r);
     }
     if (highpass.g <= 0.5) {
         overlay.g = 2.0 * color.g * highpass.g;
     } else {
         overlay.g = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - color.g) * (1.0 - highpass.g);
     }
     if (highpass.b <= 0.5) {
         overlay.b = 2.0 * color.b * highpass.b;
     } else {
         overlay.b = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - color.b) * (1.0 - highpass.b);
     }
     color.rgb = (overlay * 0.8) + (orig.rgb * 0.2);

     /* Desaturated hard light */
     highp vec3 desaturated = vec3(orig.r + orig.g + orig.b / 3.0);
     if (desaturated.r <= 0.5) {
         color.rgb = 2.0 * color.rgb * desaturated;
     } else {
         color.rgb = vec3(1.0) - vec3(2.0) * (vec3(1.0) - color.rgb) * (vec3(1.0) - desaturated);
     }
     color = (orig * 0.6) + (color * 0.4);

     /* Add back some color */
     highp float average = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;
     color.rgb += (average - color.rgb) * (1.0 - 1.0 / (1.001 - 0.45));

     gl_FragColor = (color * clarity) + (orig * (1.0 - clarity));
 }
);
#else
NSString *const kGPUImageClarityFragmentShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform float clarity;
 uniform vec2 textureSize;
 varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
 void main() {
     vec4 color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
     vec4 orig = color;

     /* High pass filter */
     vec4 highpass = color * 5.0;

     float dx = 1.0 / textureSize.x;
     float dy = 1.0 / textureSize.y;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(-dx, -dy)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(dx, -dy)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(dx, dy)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(-dx, dy)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(-dx * 2.0, -dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(dx * 2.0, -dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(dx * 2.0, dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
     highpass += texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + vec2(-dx * 2.0, dy * 2.0)) * -0.625;
     highpass.a = 1.0;

     /* Overlay blend */
     vec3 overlay = vec3(1.0);
     if (highpass.r <= 0.5) {
         overlay.r = 2.0 * color.r * highpass.r;
     } else {
         overlay.r = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - color.r) * (1.0 - highpass.r);
     }
     if (highpass.g <= 0.5) {
         overlay.g = 2.0 * color.g * highpass.g;
     } else {
         overlay.g = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - color.g) * (1.0 - highpass.g);
     }
     if (highpass.b <= 0.5) {
         overlay.b = 2.0 * color.b * highpass.b;
     } else {
         overlay.b = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - color.b) * (1.0 - highpass.b);
     }
     color.rgb = (overlay * 0.8) + (orig.rgb * 0.2);

     /* Desaturated hard light */
     vec3 desaturated = vec3(orig.r + orig.g + orig.b / 3.0);
     if (desaturated.r <= 0.5) {
         color.rgb = 2.0 * color.rgb * desaturated;
     } else {
         color.rgb = vec3(1.0) - vec3(2.0) * (vec3(1.0) - color.rgb) * (vec3(1.0) - desaturated);
     }
     color = (orig * 0.6) + (color * 0.4);

     /* Add back some color */
     float average = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;
     color.rgb += (average - color.rgb) * (1.0 - 1.0 / (1.001 - 0.45));

     gl_FragColor = (color * clarity) + (orig * (1.0 - clarity));
 }
);
#endif

@implementation GPUImageClarityFilter

@synthesize clarity = _clarity;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization and teardown

- (id)init;
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithFragmentShaderFromString:kGPUImageClarityFragmentShaderString]))
    {
        return nil;
    }

    clarityUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"clarity"];
    self.clarity = 0.0;

    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Accessors

- (void)setClarity:(GLfloat)clarity;
{
    _clarity = clarity;

    [self setFloat:_clarity forUniform:clarityUniform program:filterProgram];
}

@end
```

One other thing I thought of doing is applying GPUImage's built-in low pass and high pass filters, but I get the feeling that would end up a rather clunky solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably due to `textureSize` not being a standard uniform that is provided for you as part of a GPUImageFilter. `inputImageTexture` and `textureCoordinate` are standard uniforms provided by one of these filters, and it looks like you're providing the `clarity` uniform.

Since `textureSize` isn't set, it will default to 0.0. Your `1.0 / textureSize.x` calculation will then divide by zero, which tends to lead to black frames in an iOS fragment shader.

You could either calculate and provide that uniform, or instead take a look at basing your custom filter on GPUImage3x3TextureSamplingFilter instead. That filter base class passes in the result of `1.0 / textureSize.x` as the `texelWidth` uniform (and the matching `texelHeight` for the vertical component). You don't have to calculate this. In fact, it also calculates the texture coordinates of the surrounding 8 pixels, so you can cut out four of the calculations above and convert those to non-dependent texture reads. You'd just need to calculate the four texture reads based on `2 * texelWidth` and `2 * texelHeight` to finish off the remaining four reads.

You may in fact be able to break this operation into multiple passes to save on calculations, doing a small box blur, then an overlay blend, then the last stage of this filter. That could speed this up further.

Comment: Thanks Brad I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Spent some time fiddling around with it, but sadly I'm not familiar enough with writing shaders to figure out how to integrate the 3x3TextureSamplingFilter. Instead, I just played around with some hard coded values for textureSize and landed on `320.0` giving me a nifty effect.

Comment: Damn, and of course that only works if the input image is of a specific dimension.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can override

```
(void)setupFilterForSize:(CGSize)filterFrameSize
```

Method to setup width & height factor like `GPUImageSharpenFilter`.